# Laravel 5 -> pass second argument to Mail::send method

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I want to modify the create method in my AuthController. A mail with a verification link should be send to the users email after he send the registration form. It's almost done, but I have a problem, passing the users details into the function.

Here is what I have right now:

```
Mail::send('mails.registrierung', $data, function($message){
    $message->from('registrierung@junperbo.de', 'Registrierung');
    $message->to('email@yxz.de');
});
```

But it's clear, that a hardcoded email is not working. So I want to pass the created user to the function. I tried to `global $user` within the function (no success). I also tried to pass a second argument  like:

```
Mail::send('mails.registrierung', $data, function($message, $user) {
    $message->from('registrierung@junperbo.de', 'Registrierung');
    $message->to($user->email);
});
```

The result is this error message (for the line Mail::send(....)):

> Missing argument 2 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::App\Http\Controllers\Auth{closure}()

My whole create method:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'benutzername' => $data['benutzername'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'bestaetigt' => 0,
        'verfikations_schluessel' => str_random(60)
    ]);

    $data['user'] = $user;

    Mail::send('mails.registrierung', $data, function($message, $user){
        $message->from('registrierung@junperbo.de', 'Registrierung');
        $message->to($user->email);
    });

    return $user;
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can created a array() with all your data, then pass the array to the Mail function.

```
            $data = array('email'=>$request->input('Email'), 'nombre'=>$request->input('Nombre'));

            \Mail::send('email.action', ['data' => $data] , function ($message) use ($data) {
                //remitente
                $message->from(env('CONTACT_MAIL'), env('CONTACT_NAME'));
                //asunto
                $message->subject('Validación de Cuenta');
                //receptor
                $message->to($data['email'], $data['nombre']);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! The `...use ($data)...` was the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @smartrahat's correct answer, you can also use the `use` keyword to make the variable available within the function:

```
Mail::send('mails.registrierung', $data, function ($message) use ($user) {
    $message->from('registrierung@junperbo.de', 'Registrierung');
    $message->to($user->email);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the `$data['email']` in your service container. No need to define `$data['user'] = $user;`.

1. Change the `function($message,$user)` to `function($message)`.
2. And use `$message->to($data['email'])`

As your second argument of `send()` function is `$data`, you can use any value of `$data` inside `Mail::send()`